# Safari Web Extension Manifest V3 - Don't open application window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a browser extension that uses manifest V3 that I'd like to publish for Safari on macOS (NOT for iOS).

I used the steps here to convert it to a Safari web extension: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/converting_a_web_extension_for_safari

```bash
xcrun safari-web-extension-converter --macos-only --bundle-identifier com.my_org.extension ./build
```

This generated a Safari web extension XCode project. I can open the XCode project and run it, and it everything works just fine [following the instructions here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/running_your_safari_web_extension)

However, it opens up an application in the macOS dock that says, for example:

> My Org's extension is currently on. You can turn it off in Safari Extensions preferences.

I can't seem to find a way to have the extension *not* open up this application window.

I don't need any sort of communication between the extension and macOS, this is all strictly in-browser using service workers for background tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what to me is a baffling design choice, is seems like this is just the way that Safari extensions are packaged and deployed- as macOS Apps.

There is no way to distribute a Safari extension without an accompanying app. Trying out the top extensions, most of them just have the app open up Safari's settings to enable the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by adding persistent:false explicitly in manifest

```json
{
  "description": "description",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "short_name": "EXT Name",
  "name": "EXT Name",
  "background": { "service_worker": "background.js","persistent":false },
  "action": { "default_popup": "popup.html", "default_icon": "icon128.png" },
  "icons": { "128": "icon128.png" },
  "content_scripts": [{ "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>"], "js": ["contentScript.js"] }],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "cookies", "storage", "tabs", "webNavigation"],
  "host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
}
```